# Estimating stopping time for nonlinear drag force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, dimensional-analysis, drag

Given a nonlinear drag force of the form $f = -bv^n$, how do I **estimate** the stopping time of an object of mass $m$ and initial velocity $v_0$?

I know how to do it from integration exactly: $t_{stop} = -\frac{m}{b}\int_{v_0}^0\frac{dv}{v^n}$, but I was told that only dimensional analysis can be used to get the same result as well, or at least that it can be seen that dimensional analysis works for only a limited range of $n$ values.

The characteristic timescale for this system should be $\tau = \frac{m}{bv_0^{n-1}}$, but I don't know how to get the numerical factors correct.

How could only dimensional analysis warn me about the fact that the result might be nonsensical for some $n$?

Comment: Well, you want to solve the equation $\partial v/ \partial t = - v/t_{stop}$. Depending on $n$, this might have an exact solution.

Comment: Isn’t your integral divergent?

Comment: Dimensional analysis can’t give you numerical factors.

Comment: @G.Smith It isn't divergent for $n < 1$. Also, I am not looking to solve for the numerical factors but merely **estimate** : 1) $t_{stop}$ and 2) that dimensional analysis falls short for some values of $n$.

Comment: Drag forces are usually modeled with $n=1$ or $n=2$, not $n<1$.

Comment: Dimensional analysis can’t give you estimates of numerical factors.

Comment: @G.Smith You are right. For a general drag $f = -bv^n$ then, what should be the stopping time? Can one say something about the result without calculating it exactly? That's the question.

Comment: Statements without calculation to back them are numerology. The most dimensional analysis can tell you is what dimensionless combinations of factors the result can depend upon, it cannot tell you what that dependence is. Furthermore, as pointed out, you cannot rely upon your integral to converge and in the standard cases of $n=1,2$, it does not. In those cases people instead define a "characteristic" time to be when the velocity becomes "close enough" to zero. The definition of this time is, however, completely dependent upon the functional form of the exact solution.

Comment: Not dimension analysis, but power analysis in the integral. For $n=1$, the stopping time is finite. For $n>1$, the particle will not stop. The dragging force is diminishing too fast to stop the movement in the low speed limit, at the final stage of motion.